Whats the point of having signs for those who believe or those who are certain?
Surely if you already believed or were certain you wouldn't need any signs. Like 45:3 says signs for those who believe. 51:20 says signs for those who are sure.

Signs are for what? to believe Islam and become a Muslim, yes but not limited to them.
For example Ibrahim PBUH was a prophet when he asked Allah a sign (وَ إِذْ قَالَ إِبْرَاهِيمُ رَبِّ أَرِنِي كَيْفَ تُحْيِي الْمَوْتَيٰ قَالَ أَوَلَمْ تُؤْمِنْ قَالَ بَلَيٰ وَ لَكِنْ لِيَطْمَئِنَّ قَلْبِي) and Allah AWJ shew him the realm of the heavens and the earth so that he would be among the certain in faith (وَ كَذَلِكَ نُرِي إِبْرَاهِيمَ مَلَكُوتَ السَّمَاوَاتِ وَ الْأَرْضِ وَ لِيَكُونَ مِنَ الْمُوقِنِين)!
So was Zakariyyah PBUH when his praying was accepted and he asked for a sign (قَالَ رَبِّ اجْعَلْ لِي آيَةً قَالَ آيَتُكَ أَلَّا تُكَلِّمَ النَّاسَ ثَلَاثَ لَيَالٍ سَوِيًّا)
and who said someone who believes simply believe? For example in Quran we read "يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا آمِنُوا" which is translated into "O you who have believed, believe". This is because believing is a graded concept. Like for example you study a lemma in mathematics, learn and understand it, then several years later you again think about it and what now you understand of it is way deeper. Like the understanding of a teacher who has taught a lesson for years from what he teaches is not the same as the understanding of a youth who learns the issue for the first time.
In Quran the signs are sometimes for the disbelievers to prove them Islam is right and Quran is revealed by Allah AWJ, the God, and sometimes are for the believers to learn and grow: "ذَلِكَ الْكِتَابُ لَا رَيْبَ فِيهِ هُدًي لِلْمُتَّقِينَ" which reads "This is the Book; in it is guidance sure, without doubt, to those who fear Allah", or that He says "قُلْ هُوَ لِلَّذِينَ آمَنُوا هُدًي وَ شِفَاءٌ" which reads "That [Quran] is a Guide and a Healing to those who believe"

4:136 doesn't make sense by your explanation. What is it that people are believing in before they even believe in Allah and his messenger ? There is nothing in the quran to suggest disbelievers it is the god of Islam which is true. The quran seems to take it for granted that monotheists will believe it. Not so. Other than that your whole explanation is extra quranic, so show me a verse which talks about belief as you say. That is a deepening rather than changing conviction. Abraham clearly didn't have sure faith and that's why God showed him signs and he became a prophet.

@DarabMasood, "قَالَتِ الْأَعْرَابُ آمَنَّا قُلْ لَمْ تُؤْمِنُوا وَ لَكِنْ قُولُوا أَسْلَمْنَا وَ لَمَّا يَدْخُلِ الْإِيمَانُ فِي قُلُوبِكُمْ" which reads "The bedouins say, 'We have believed.' Say, 'You have not [yet] believed; but say [instead], 'We have submitted,' for faith has not yet entered your hearts." Next, tell me whether if your beliefs are as strong and deep as the holy prophet's beliefs? Also tell me what's the difference between "یؤمنون" and "یؤقنون"? These are not extra-Quranic ...

How's this verse relevant ? There's nothing here about degrees of faith as you say. Nothing about doubt. All it says is people don't have faith. Which presumably means certainty. Again you avoid the question. What is faith, if not certainty ? And what does it mean to have signs for those who are certain ? What are they certain of, if its not the very thing the signs are supposed to make them certain of like God's majesty and power ? That is the context 45:3 and 51:20. Stick to these verses if you would be helpful.

@DarabMasood, that believing and even being certain is graded is obvious to me, maybe due to decades of personal experiences in religion and science :) It is so much backed with Quran and Hadeeth, and scholarly ideas. Ibrahim asked what he asked while he was already a prophet, not only a simple believer, but you can simply disagree. Tried to be helpful but no insist, maybe you should experience it by yourself, to see no contradiction appears here. Godspeed.
